# Is there a master list of iOS automation references for getting child elements (ie window.buttons() )?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, automated-tests, ios-ui-automation

I am having difficulty when I try to refer to a searchbar in my app when performing automated testing. 
If I use something like:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().searchBars()
```

this does not appear to be a valid get method. Is there a master list of get methods for UIAElements (ex .buttons(), .views(), .listViews()) or is there a general rule? What is the proper get method for UISearchBars?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't appear to be a valid method? Do you get an error? An empty list? You can use this reference (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009903) for all the methods to call, but remember that this method doesn't search the element hierarchy. It just filters the children of the element you called it on.

Comment: that list was exactly what I was looking for. I believe I tried searchBars but it gave a UIANilelement exception. When I have access to the code tomorrow, I'll update the question with the exact error I am seeing in the automator. Thanks!

Comment: May be that element is not present as a searchbar in your window or not accessible . please see target.LogElementTree(); and see that the status of search bar . sometimes they appear as static text there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference is here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009771

UAISearchBar inherits from UIATextFields so there you find the method 'searchBars'.